# Samsung P2250 odd flickering

Tags: external-display

I noticed odd flickering on my external monitor, connected via HDMI. It alternates between black and brown, as seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7xJlCRTLZ8&feature=em-upload_owner

The issue is not present on the main monitor and switching to projector only mode doesn't help.

How can I fix this? What might be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried changing the refresh rate in your graphic card's settings?

Comment: @TomDamon Yes. Same thing on 30i/59p/60p